# List comprehension on nested for loop

Tags: python, loops, nested, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,6,8,1,2,3]
```

I want to iterate over list and print list of numbers starting and ending with same number.I have done it with for loop:

```
iniatializing = 1
for i in l1:
 for j in range(iniatializing,len(l1)):
     if i == l1[j]:
         starting_point =l1.index(i)
         print(l1[starting_point:j+1])
     iniatializing += 1
```

But how can this be done by using list comprehension?

Comment: Your code currently doesn't find all sublists starting and ending in the same number, it only finds sublists that start and end with the first element of the whole list. Is that intentional? Can your explain more clearly what output you would ideally want to see from the script? Also, what if `l1` was `[1,2,3,6,8,1,2,3,1]`? Would you expect 1 result? 3? 4? 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you want to achieve is:

For each `i`, `j` (`i < j`), if `l1[i]==l2[j]`, print the subset between `i` and `j`.

```py
n = len(l1)
[l1[i:j+1] for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1, n) if l1[i] == l1[j]]
```

EDIT: answer to the question about the original implementation.

```py
l1 = [1,2,3,6,8,1,2,3]

iniatializing = 1
for i in l1:
 for j in range(iniatializing,len(l1)):
     if i == l1[j]:
         starting_point =l1.index(i)
         print(l1[starting_point:j+1])
 iniatializing += 1

#[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 1]
#[2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 2]
#[3, 6, 8, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Initially I was aiming for what you have solved with list comprehension.But the problem I faced even with for loop is that it just showed first occurence:[[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 1], [2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 2], [3, 6, 8, 1, 2, 3]] All these list should be repeated twice as (1,2,3) is even at last of the list.Could you help with that?Hope I am able to make myself clear.

Comment: @user222807 Your code updates `initializing` too early. It should be updated after the `j`-loop finishes.  Currently it is inside the `j`- loop.

Comment: I have tried that .It gives same output.

Comment: Please see the edit above.